Gitlab CI job on merge only, with dependencies?
I have Gitlab CI with dependencies.
There is a particular test that is expensive, so I want it to run only upon merge request.
vs2019-windows:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    ...
  tags:
    ...
  needs: ["clang++", "g++"]

Search online, here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html and here Trigger jobs in gitlab-ci on merge request, I found that adding
  only:
    - merge_requests

or the now recommended (?)
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

actually breaks the whole CI because it says that the job depends on jobs that do not exists.
If I remove the dependencies this becomes the only job in the queue.
How do I make a job in the CI to be only executed upon merge request? maintaining dependencies?

All the jobs that vs2019-windows depends on need to run on a merge_request_event as well, otherwise you will get the errors you see right now

I see, but I want to run the rest on all events, not only on merge request.

@MichaelKotzjan, I added workflow:   rules:     - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'     - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG     - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH, so all jobs run on merge request, but I am back to the initial state: the job always runs.

Ah I see, seems like you only set rules for the entire pipeline. You can also set rules for specific jobs. In Your case add a rules section to v2019-windows that allows it to run on merge_request-events and afterwards add one line with just - when: never to prevent it to run in all other cases

@MichaelKotzjan, I mean that I added the workflow... lines above after your advice. So, is that ok, should I just add - when: never for the job?

I just added an answer to have more space for code ;)

I believe what you want is this:
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

vs2019-windows:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    ...
  tags:
    ...
  needs: ["clang++", "g++"]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - when: never

Gitlab rules are processed from top to bottom, the first matching rule applies. So this setup would run pipelines if CI_COMMIT_TAG is set, if your CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is equal to your CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH or for Merge Requests. If you want to run jobs in different scenarios like web pipelines or schedules you need to add them to the workflow rules as well.
The rules for your job vs2019-windows will allow the job to run on merge_request_events and prevent the job from running in all other cases.
EDIT:
Thnaks for providing your pipelines, now I understand where I went wrong with my solution. Since you do not want to run vs-2019-windows for any merge request related pipeline you need a rule like:
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  when: never

If you keep only this rule for the vs-2019-windows job it will use your workflow rules and only exclude the job for merge request events. This way the will still run for every pipeline on your CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH, including your schedules. You could add another rule to exclude the job from your schedules as well if needed.

mmm, that disabled all testing inside merge requests.

@alfC oh yeah of course, my mistake! Now that we did not add the merge_request_event to the workflow:rules section no pipeline will be created for MRs. I will update my answer!

I followed your instructions, and it looks like the result is the opposite of what I want. The job tries to run during the merge request pipeline but not during the merge to master, which is what I want. https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads#L293

There is a merge result pipeline that runs after your code is merged, but it is a premium/ultimate feature. I'm not sure if thats what you want. Since your repo is public, could you give me two links, one to a pipeline where you want the job to run and one to one where it is currently running but you do not want it to? That would probably help me

here it is, here it is a pipeline that ran upon merge: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/pipelines/1379632561, and this is a pipeline that ran inside during a merge request push https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/pipelines/1379587049. Note that the second has a job called vc2019-windows, but the first doesn't have it. I want the opposite. (the reason is that vc2019-windows is expensive and I don't mind to run it only after merging with master)

@alfC please look at my update

“you need a rule like”, where? for windows-2019 or for the general job?

This is what I have (and worked the opposite as intended): https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads#L18

Sorry, I meant just for the windows-2019 job. Note that this is not the exact rule as you currently have in your workflow rules. You need to add a when: never to the windows job to exclude it from MR events

In the first code you put - before when; and in the second you don't. Are both valid?

@alfC both are valid, but mean different things. In the first code block the - defines a new rule without an if-section which means that it matches everything. In the second code block without the - the when belongs to the previous rule

Sorry it doesn't work, workflow:  // ... //  rules:  //  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG  //  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH  //  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'  // ... // vs2019-windows: // ... // rules:  // - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'  // when: never https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads#L289 and it doesn't work (the jobs is not executed during the Request nor at the actual Merge later).

Alright, in that case I'm really unsure in which kind of pipelines you want to run this job...

sorry if I was not clear, the idea is that for most pushes this test wouldn't run, only when or around merging (with master for example). The idea is to run this test only at a critical point. In any case, thank you for your help. I am going to try again with - when: never (with the dash).
